# Is there a grammatical difference with this IDO pronoun then possessive pronoun, or vice versa?

Tags: pronouns, possessive-pronouns

> There's still time to make this a rewarding experience for you and your clients!

> There's still time to make this a rewarding experience for your clients and you!

Comment: 'You' in the second sentence might be better replaced with the more emphatic 'yourself'.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a grammatical difference with this IDO pronoun then possessive pronoun, or vice versa?

I had not the faintest idea what "IDO pronoun" referred to, and its use will not help others. (Ido is a constructed language derived from Reformed Esperanto)

You seem to have misunderstood "you and your clients". You is a pronoun (in this case, in the objective case as a result of being the object of the preposition"for") and "your clients" is a noun phrase - also governed by "for".

The "your" in "your clients" acts as a determiner.

The combination of a preposition (for) and a noun phrase (you and your clients) creates a modifier - in this case "for you and your clients" acts adjectivally and modifies "experience".

There's still time {to make [verb] this [direct object] a rewarding experience [indirect object] for you and your clients [adjunct]!} adverbial infinitive clause modifying "time".

If you are worried about word order, both are possible, but sentences  that exhort someone to do something to benefit your profit margin are usually primarily addressed to the person who is going to spend the money, i.e. "you": the person you are addressing.

Emphasis is given to this person by placing "you" first.

Comment: I suspect that OP is using  "IDO" as an abbreviation for "indirect object".

Answer (score 0):

When you ask for "grammatical difference," you have assumed that both are grammatical and "correct." So, let's set that Q aside.

*Pragmatics:*
The order follows an **implied order of significance**: "Rewarding experience for A, (and of course, to some extent,) B." Accordingly, you decide what comes first.

In a specific case where one of the two words is the first person personal pronoun, it is advised that it always come latter, not before. "It helps both you and me," not "It helps both me and you."

Comment: I suppose I was asking "if" there was a grammatical difference on the sentence-level in which I was unaware. I was leaning toward the example you offed in the order of significance. Thank you.